# NOT NULL constraint failed: jobs_job.created_by_id IntegrityError at /jobs/add/

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-orm

I am trying to enable the user to be able to add job and after filling the form i got that error. Here is my code:

[image]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_description = models.TextField()
    long_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import AddJobForm
from .models import Job

def job_detail(request, job_id):
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    return render(request, 'jobs/job_detail.html', {'job': job})

@login_required
def add_job(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddJobForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            job = form.save(commit=True)
            job.created_by = request.user
            job.save()

            return redirect('dashboard')

    else:
        form = AddJobForm()

    return render(request, 'jobs/add_job.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Job


class AddJobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['title','short_description','long_description']
```

What do i need to do to solve this error? I have try to remove the `commit=True`, from `views.py` and I have try to remove sqlite3 and do the migrations again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save the object without a value for `created_by` (hence the error message), then assign a value for that field and save again. You should change

```
job = form.save(commit=True)
```

to

```
job = form.save(commit=False)
```

so that the first `.save` doesn't actually try to commit anything to the database. It is simply used to construct the `Job` instance so that you can complete any missing values and actually save it using `job.save()`.

Note that if you omit the `commit=` argument it is assumed to be `True`.